I should be getting a key error to exercise the except branch of a try statement, replaces value with none instead
For a school assignment im given a dictionary of hockey teams with the team names as key and team captain as values, I'm supposed to search the dictionary for the team and display the corresponding captain.
We are required to use try/except branch since entering a non existent team should produce an error, but when I input a non existent team it just replaces the team captain with 'none' and makes up a new team.
#Program Name: Question 1
#Program Purpose: Search through a Dictionary 
#Author: Mathew Jankuloski
#Date: 2024-04-04

#Declare given Dictionary
teams_and_captains = {
'Colorado Avalanche' : 'Gabriel Landeskog',
'Columbus Blue Jackets':'Boone Jenner',
'Dallas Stars' : 'Jamie Benn',
'Detroit Red Wings' : 'Dylan Larkin',
'Edmonton Oilers' : 'Connor Mcdavid',
'Florida Panthers' : 'Aleksander Barkov',
'Los Angeles Kings' : 'Anze Kopitar',
'Minnesota Wild' : 'Jared Spurgeon',
'Montreal Canadiens' : 'Nick Suzuki',
'Nashville Predators' : 'Roman Josi',
'New Jersey Devils' : 'Nico Hischier',
'New York Islanders' : 'Anders Lee',
'New York Rangers' : 'Jacob Trouba'}

userInput = input("Please enter a team to look up it's captain or X to quit: ")
userInput = userInput.title()

while userInput != "X":
    try:
        captain = teams_and_captains.get(userInput)
        print(f"{captain} is the captain for the {userInput}")
    except:
        print(f'{userInput} could not be found')
    userInput = input("Please enter a team to look up it's captain or X to quit: ")
    userInput=userInput.title()

print("Have a nice day")


The .get() method of dictionaries exists so that you can retrieve a value without any possibility of error - if the key doesn't exist, the second parameter (None by default) is returned.  You just want normal dictionary lookup here - teams_and_captains[userInput].

Also, if you expect to get a KeyError, use except KeyError, to not hide any other errors.
